# Transparent or Invisible

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to use an ImageView without any background. I know that I can use

```
imageView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
```

and

```
imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

I was wondering which one is more efficient? or any extra solution?

Comment: What do you want `ImageView` for then? Why not take a normal `View` ?

Comment: @Manohar this is as same as my question. using a view with INVISIBLE visibility or An ImageView with Transparent background?

Comment: At least as written, you are comparing two methods on an ImageView. A View might be more efficient than an ImageView, indeed. But what exactly is your purpose then? Just to have some empty space in the layout? Maybe just use some margin or padding, as this might be even more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

The two lines don't have the same purpose, so you don't really have to compare their efficiency.

The first one changes the view visibility, so the entire view is still drawn, takes the space in the layout, but is not visible at the moment.

On the other hand, an `ImageView` with an invisible background can still be visible if it has an `android:src` that is not null.

Here is a random example that uses the two together: it's an imageview with a transparent background, but with a source image, for which the visibility changes based on a certain condition, so it can be `INVISIBLE` or `VISIBLE`:

```
 <ImageView
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:visibility="@{!obj.mealbox}"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_list_sorting_close"
      app:tint="@color/dish_icon_color" />
```

Since your purpose is to

> use an ImageView without any background.

only the second option will work.

Comment: The first option will work too. because I just wanna my ImageView's background to be visible. My question is which one is the more efficient way?

Answer (score -1):

you can use imageView.setAlpha(127);

Comment: This is indeed equivalent to setting the view visibility to INVISIBLE, but it's not useful for the purpose stated - to show an imageView but without a background.